# practical way to navigate into index folders for searching multiple pdf files in Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, search, context-menu, adobe-reader

while I'm learning for exams i need often to search multiple pdf files for some text. I have done it till now using adobe reader.The Problem is that adobe reader or all other pdf viewers i tried ("PDF-XChange Viewer","Foxit Reader" ..) have an unpratical search interface in the way that if one needs to choose another index folder one must navigate again all over through  the way there! It also doesn't recognise shortcuts.

I tried  wingrep which is really good tool and its integrated into context menu but it doesn't support searching into pdf files :( also tried Docfetcher but it's not really user friendly and not integrated into the context menu.
[image: search browse interface][image]

Is there any anyway anytool(except "Windows Search indexing") which let user navigate fast between index folders( like typing directory into address bar or a has search function in context menu) ?

Comment: [PDF iFilter for Windows Search](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/ifilter/index.html#downifilter) - see answer in duplicate.

Comment: Windows search is really ugly. read please the Question carefully again

Comment: Reopened after your edit.

Answer (score 1):

Give [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) a try. It's free, integrates into the context menu, and searches within .pdf files.